# FirebaseUI-web: no recognised user after account login

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

The Firebase authListener shows the account chooser but doesn't recognise any user the first time I try to login.

Then, trying to login again for a second time, FirebaseUI skips the account chooser and immediately redirects back, after which the Firebase authListener *does* recognise the user. The same is true for the Google account chooser as for "Sign in with email" and choosing the same Google address.

This problem makes all my users need to press the login button twice. Once for the account chooser and a second time to actually login with the user now recognised.

Here is my build:

#### Firebase initialisation

```javascript
    firebase.initializeApp(config.firebase)
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        return console.log('found this user! ', user)
      }
      console.log('no user found during authListener!')
    })
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()
    .then(result => { console.log(result.user) })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error) })
```

#### Here is what happens when the login page is mounted

```javascript
    let ui = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance()
    if (!ui) {
      ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())
    }
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig)
```

#### Here is my config:

```javascript
    uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: '/',
      signInOptions: [
        {
          provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          requireDisplayName: false
        },
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      ],
      tosUrl: 'localhost'
    }
```

Versions:
`"firebase": "^5.0.4",`
`"firebaseui": "^3.0.0",`
PS:
My website is an SPA

Comment: Facing exactly the same problem, with firebase ui v3.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

I "solved" this problem by adding the following to the config object:

```
credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE
```

This turns off the account chooser entirely, instead prompting users to type in their email address, resulting in a much nicer user experience IMHO compared to the ugly and confusing account chooser.